# LibGDX android generate random position in screen

Tags: java, android, random, libgdx

I want to generate random position inside my android device screen using LibGDX.
my `sprite` `width` is 150, `height` is 150 aswell, so `OFFSET = 150`.

my idea was to get the width, height of the screen, generate a random number while doing `width - 150` and `height - 150`.

Like this:

```
    int x = 150 + Config.RANDOM.nextInt( (int) (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - Config.OFFSET) );
    int y = 150 + Config.RANDOM.nextInt( (int) (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Config.OFFSET) );
```

Tested it out, but unfortunately, the sprites sometimes just gets out of the screen.
These are the debugging outputs:

```
03-05 15:50:22.432: I/System.out(4141): X: 828 Y:1384
03-05 15:50:23.432: I/System.out(4141): X: 391 Y:520
03-05 15:50:24.452: I/System.out(4141): X: 230 Y:917
03-05 15:50:25.462: I/System.out(4141): X: 872 Y:808
03-05 15:50:26.472: I/System.out(4141): X: 827 Y:963
03-05 15:50:27.482: I/System.out(4141): X: 595 Y:382
```

My screen `width/height (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / Gdx.graphics.getHeight):`

```
03-05 15:52:33.862: I/System.out(5771):  Width: 1080.0 Height: 1776.0
```

Did I generate a random position wrong?

Also I am using a portrait mode, i don't do `camera.combine` because it rotates my `sprites` by 180 degrees.

```
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(w, h);
            camera.setToOrtho(true, w, h);
            camera.update();


    public void render() {
        this.spriteRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(this.instance.camera.combined);
        this.spriteRenderer.begin();
        if (!this.ballon.isPoping()) {
            Sprite s = this.ballon.getSprite();
            spriteRenderer.draw(s, 50, 50, s.getWidth(), s.getHeight());
        }
//      else {
//          if (!this.ballon.isPoped()) {
//              Sprite s = this.ballon.getCurrentAnimation();
//              this.spriteRenderer.draw(s, this.ballon.getX(),
//                      this.ballon.getY(),
//                      this.ballon.getSprite().getWidth() * SpriteConfiguration.BALLON_SCALE,
//                      this.ballon.getSprite().getHeight() * SpriteConfiguration.BALLON_SCALE);                
//              this.ballon.processAnimation();
//          }
//      }
        this.spriteRenderer.end();
    }
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: the sprites sometimes just gets out of the screen.

Comment: Sorry, my previous answer won't fix your problem. The orthocam does default to have 0,0 in the corner when you call `setToOrtho`. You may need to show your code for how you are generating your sprites and how you are drawing them. Something's not right if using `cam.combined` results in rotated sprites. Your debug proves that you're generating numbers correctly, so the problem is in how you're using your camera or placing your sprites.

Comment: After adding combines it works fine, but now my sprites are like vertically transformed, it's top is looking down, basically 180 degrees rotated, i've added my drawing

Answer (score 0):

I believe sprite position is set as top left corner of the sprite on the screen.

You wanted to generate values between <0; width - 150>. However, your code generates numbers between <150; width>.

Use this to generate <0; width - OFFSET> values

```
int x = Config.RANDOM.nextInt( (int) (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - Config.OFFSET) );
int y = Config.RANDOM.nextInt( (int) (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Config.OFFSET) );
```

or if you want  <150; width - 150> range

```
int x = Config.OFFSET + Config.RANDOM.nextInt( (int) (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - Config.OFFSET * 2) );
int y = Config.OFFSET + Config.RANDOM.nextInt( (int) (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Config.OFFSET * 2) );
```

I find it easier to wrap my head around edge cases to find out, if my random generator will work. Just try setting lowest possible x, y first, then maximum and try if they work. After that just replace it with random.. ie:

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
```

then try

```
int x = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - Config.OFFSET;
int y = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Config.OFFSET;
```

after you confirmed edge cases are correct, just replace it to one of the two I've stated earlier.